# How can switch between applications in a win10 guest using remote-viewer from a linux host (spice protocol)?

Tags: spice

I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I connect to virtual machines via remote-viewer and with the SPICE protocol. The guest OS is a Windows 10 and very often I have to switch between windows in the guest OS. But when I hit alt+tab then the window switches from the remote-viewer to whatever other window I have open on my host OS (Ubuntu). Therefore I need another shortcut for use inside the guest OS. Just a few minutes ago I found that actually I could use Super(the windows logo key) + alt + tab, but this is a rather uncomfortable shortcut. At least I find this uncomfortable. Is there a way to change the shortcuts?

During my search via google I only found shortcuts/hotkeys, which changed the behavior of the remote-viewer like maximizing the window and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I need to this without a third party app.

Comment: Which remote-viewer are you using?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I guess it is one that comes with virt-viewer. I have this installed: 
ii  virt-viewer                                   7.0-2build2                                 amd64        Displaying the graphical console of a virtual machine

But I invoke it with "remote-viewer spice://[IP:port]". Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

The following post may contain the answer by user Yonatan :
[How do I prevent Virt-Viewer from capturing keyboard shortcuts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700625/how-do-i-prevent-virt-viewer-from-capturing-keyboard-shortcuts)

> Just press and release the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys
> (together).  Once you release those keys will get out of the
> capturing.  To get into capturing keyboard do the same thing (press
> and release the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys once again).